# How to do GCM Registration from broadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I am calling `GCMRegistrar.register(context, Constants.GCM_SENDER_ID)` from a BroadcastReceiver(Boot complete receiver) but it throws ReceiverCallNotAllowedException then I started a seprate thread from broadcastreceiver and from thread I called `GCMRegistrar.register(context, Constants.GCM_SENDER_ID)` again I got the same exception.

Then I started an IntentService from broadcastreceiver and from intent service I called

```
GCMRegistrar.register(context, Constants.GCM_SENDER_ID)
```

then I got sending message to a handler on a dead thread which comes because for android 2.3 it uses google accounts and I think it does some async task.

Now is there any way to achieve GCMRegistrar.register(context, Constants.GCM_SENDER_ID) successfully from a broadcastreceiver

Answer (score 2):

GCMRegistrar is deprecated. The better alternative is to use [GoolgeCloudMessaging](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html) class.

To register using this you can call

```
 String id = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context).register(senderId);
```

Comment: This class requires Google Play services version 3.1 or higher. so I don't want to use this ...

Comment: you can simply add that to your libs.. what is the problem?

Comment: you can add the jar to the project

Comment: Ohh then nice , I will try and will let you know

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to using the new `GoogleCloudMessaging` class, as was suggested by StinePike, but `GCMRegistrar.register` still works. I guess that for some reason you can't use it from a broadcast receiver, but you can call it (for example) from your main activity. Is there a special reason you need to call it from a broadcast receiver?

Comment: Yes I am calling it from main activity and it works fine but I want to call it from boot complete broadcastreceiver and in this case it is not working ..